# drawing an arrow using CGPointMake

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'd like to draw an arrow something like this:

[image]

How can I do something like this using CGPoint?

Answer (score 0):

In your -drawRect method of UIView subview:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, point1.x, point1.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point2.x, point2.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point3.x, point3.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point1.x, point1.y);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

Comment: what if I don't want to do this in drawRect?

Comment: If you want to do it elsewhere - you`ll have to provide a valid CGContext reference